# How to store values on one variable when i do multiple clicks on a button?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a minitable that it shows data from database,i need to store that button id when i do click on delete (button) has delete option, on it value it has an id (any button has a unique id). How could i store on one variable the values when i do click on that button?? Pls help me, now i share my code. I need to store on one variable multiple id's (ID_DetalleOTPloteo) when i do click on any different delete button. Pls help

```js
let paraBorrar = [];
    let data = {
        "respuesta": "success",
        "post": [
            {
                "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
                "ID_Cliente": "3",
                "ID_Documento": "2",
                "Subtotal_OTPloteo": "23.75",
                "Impuesto_OTPloteo": "2.85",
                "Total_OTPloteo": "26.60",
                "NumeroDocumento_OTPloteo": "000140",
                "Serie_OTPloteo": "001",
                "Fecha_OTPloteo": "2020-08-19 21:45:12",
                "Nombre_Cliente": "David Alejandro",
                "Apellido_Cliente": "Paucar Briones",
                "Telefono_Cliente": "0992896820",
                "Nombre_Documento": "Factura",
                "Impuesto_Documento": "12",
                "Cantidad_Documento": "141",
                "Serie_Documento": "001",
                "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "30",
                "Precio_OTPloteo": "3.00",
                "Importe_OTPloteo": "3.75"
            },
            [
                {
                    "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "30",
                    "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
                    "Precio_OTPloteo": "3.00",
                    "Importe_OTPloteo": "3.75"
                },
                {
                    "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "31",
                    "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
                    "Precio_OTPloteo": "7.00",
                    "Importe_OTPloteo": "8.75"
                },
                {
                    "ID_DetalleOTPloteo": "32",
                    "ID_OTPloteo": "61",
                    "Precio_OTPloteo": "9.00",
                    "Importe_OTPloteo": "11.25"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
    
    
    // Recorre los datos
    data.post[1].forEach(item => {
        // Crea contenido HTML de la fila
        // Agrega un campo oculto para saber qué es lo que se está modificando
        let html = `<tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="idPloteo[]" value="${item.ID_DetalleOTPloteo}">
                <input type="text" name="metrosTotalPloteo[]" class="metrosTotalPloteo form-control" value="${item.Precio_OTPloteo}">
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control importeMetrosPloteo" name="importeMetrosPloteo[]" value="${(item.Importe_OTPloteo)}" readonly></td>
            <td><a href="#" value="" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon eliminarMetros" type="button"><i class="icon-trash">Borrar</i></a></td>
        </tr>`;
        // Agrega fila a la tabla
        $('.tablaEditarAgregarPloteo').append(html);
    });

    // Esta función debe estar fuera del ciclo
    $(document).on('click', '.eliminarMetros', function () {
        // Obtener fila a la que pertenece el botón
        let tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        // Obtener ID de elemento a eliminar
        // Agregar a elementos por borrar
        // Eliminar fila y volver a calcular
        $(tr).remove();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table class="table table-bordered tablaEditarAgregarPloteo">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Metros</th>
                                            <th>Precio Final</th>
                                            <th>Acción</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Comment: why not you use `<input type="hidden">`

Comment: @gpl i use it but data store one by one when i need store all values on one single variable

Comment: tried javascript array?

Comment: @gpl i try it but when i close a modal and open a new one, the array its cloned and isnt empty like i want

Comment: Can we use ID_Cliente to uniquely find out the post? To find out which post ID_DetalleOTPloteo belongs to. Clearly, we need to create 2 level data structure here. 1st level for all posts and 2nd level for all ID_DetalleOTPloteo

Comment: Please explain your data structure. I am trying to understand it through google translate but many things are non translating.